# How to set iOS accessibility label permanently for a view that have access read during run time?

Tags: ios, uiview

I am reading a list of UIViews exist on the screen, during run time, and I want to permanently set their accessibility labels in the code, so every time I run after that, they have it set.

Currently what I set in subview.accessibilityLabel is not persistent.

if (![subview accessibilityLabel] || [[subview accessibilityLabel] isEqualToString:@""])
    subview.accessibilityLabel = mystring;

I don't want to directly modify the views in the nib file or view controller.

Answer (score 0):

One way to persist the settings is to save the mystring in db or configuration files (copy the configuration file to Documents folder so that it becomes mutable), and next time you run the app, the string can be loaded and assigned to the accessibilityLabel.